Bijection between natural numbers and the set of all sum of two squares in integers
Let $X$ be the set of all sum of two squares in integers. It is evident that they form a monoid with respect to multiplication, since $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)= (ac-bd)^2+ (ad+bc)^2$.
Since $X$ is countably infinite then there should exist a bijection map from $\mathbb{N}$ to $X$. Since $2=1^2+1^2$ and for any odd prime $p=a^2+b^2$ if and only if $p=1\pmod 4$. Therefore, each $n$ of the form $2^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}...p_k^{a_k}q_1^{b_1}...q_s^{b_s}$ where $p_i=1\pmod 4$ and $q_i= 3\pmod 4$ with $b_i$'s even, can be seen as an element in $X$.
Can anyone suggest any concrete bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $X$?
Any help will be appreciated.

Technically, it would be "Since $X$ is countably infinite..." Countable includes finite sets.

@ThomasAndrews: Thank you so much. I have edited it.

Sure, we define $f(0)=0, f(1)=1,$ $f(p)=p$ if $p\equiv1\pmod4$ is prime or $p=2,$ $f(p)=p^2$ if $p\equiv3\pmod 4$ is prime. Then define $f$ for the rest define $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$ for any natural numbers $m,n.$ You will need to show this defines $f$ uniquely for all natural numbers, of course.

Basically, $$f(p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_n^{a_n})=f(p_1)^{a_1}\cdots r(p_n)^{a_n}.$$

@ThomasAndrews of the uncountably many possible solutions this is probably the nicest and deserves to be posted as an answer.

@ThomasAndrews: Assume that $\mathbb{N}$ is just a set and $(X, .)$ is a semigroup and $f: \mathbb{N} \to X$ is a bijection. Then it will induce an operation $\ast_f$ on $\mathbb{N}$ such that $f$ is semigroup homomorphism. If we choose the above bijection, $\ast_f$ is the usual multiplication in $\mathbb{N}$. Is there any interesting bijection such that we get a non-trivial operation on $\mathbb{N}?$

Not when the semigroup is isomorphic to $(\mathbb N,\times).$ If $f:\mathbb N\to X$ yields an isomorphism, and $g:\mathbb N\to X$ is another bijection, this is just gives$h=g^{-1}\circ f$ is a permutation of $\mathbb N,$ and the semigroup structure on $\mathbb N$ from $g$  is just determined by $h.$ Namely, $a\star b=h^{-1}(h(a)\times h(b).$ I can't see how any of those would be interesting. I suppose we could get $\star$ identical to $\times$ when $h$ just permutes the primes.

But, for example, bitwise "or" or "and" can be gotten using rhe usual bijections between the finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N,$ where we associate a finite subset $S\subset\mathbb N$ with $\sum_{n\in S} 2^n.$ Then "bitwise or" and "bitwise and" correspond to the operations $\cup$ and $\cap,$ respectively, on the sets.

@ThomasAndrews: Thank you so much. I understand it. I was also thinking about the map $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to X$ given $n=2^{x_n-1}(2y_n-1) \mapsto (x_n, y_n) \mapsto x_n^2 +y_n^2.$ The first map is bijective, whereas the second is just a surjective. So, we may not pull back the operation of $X$ to $\mathbb{N}.$

@ThomasAndrews: Can we construct  a bijection function $g: \mathbb{N} \to X$ which is NOT multiplicative, that is, $g(mn) \neq g(m)g(n)?$

Sure, you can. They aren't very interesting.

@ThomasAndrews: I have constructed one, given by $\phi: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ such that $\phi(2k)=2k-1$ and $\phi(2k-1)=2k$, then take $g:= f \circ \phi.$ This $g$ is NOT multiplicative.  However, I cannot write down the proper expression of $g(n)$ in terms of $n$. Can you suggest some example of non-multiplicative bijection $g: \mathbb{N} \to X?$ If we have such $g$, then we can construct an operation $\ast_g$ on $\mathbb{N}$ given by $g(a\ast_g b)= g(a).g(b),$ which is useful for me.

Yes, you can compose my map with most permutations of $\mathbb N,$ or with most permutations of $X.$ A general such bijection goes in reverse, $g:X\to\mathbb N,$ with $$g(x)=\left|{y\in X\mid y<x}\right|$$ then $f=g^{-1}:\mathbb N\to X$ give $f(n)$ equal to the the $n+1$st smallest element of $X.$ So $f(0)$ is the smallest element of $X,$ $f(1)$ is the second smallest. But that is hard to define algebraically, and tricky to compute (but it is computable, just not very efficiently.) It has the advantage that it works for any infinite $X\subseteq\mathbb N.$ But $f$ will not be multiplicative.

This $f=g^{-1}$ is not multiplicative, since $$f(0)=0,f(1)=1,f(2)=2,f(3)=4,f(4)=5,d(5)=6,f(6)=9\neq f(2)f(3).$$

There are uncountably many bijections $\pi:\mathbb N\to\mathbb. N.$ So there are that many bijections to $\mathbb N\to X.$  Such a map $\pi$ will, when composed with my multiplicative bijection will be multiplicative iff $\pi$ is multiplicative, and. thus, in particular, $\pi$ must permute primes, and then a general $n$ would go by taking the prime factorization of $n$ and apply $\pi$ to the primes alone, keeping the exponents.

In particular, any $\pi$ with $\pi(0)\neq 0$ or $\pi(1)\neq 1$ will give a non-multiplicative $\mathbb N\to X,$ and given any permutation of primes, there is only one permutation of the rest of the elements which iis multiplicative, and uncountably which are. And, of course, there are uncountably many that are not permutations of the primes - either there is some prime sent to a comosite or some composite sent to a prime. This still means the cardinalities of the sets of multiplicate and non-multiplicative functions are the same...

... but I suspect there is a probability measure on the set of permutations $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that the measure of the multiplicative permutations is $0.$ (Note: We are using multiplicative here to mean $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$ for all $m,n,$ but that is not the usual meaning, The usual meaning is $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$ when $\gcd(m,n)=1.$)

@ThomasAndrews: Thank you so much for these amazing comments. It helped me like anything. By the way, do you know any reference where I can find the formula for $\phi(m,n)$ with $x_m.x_n= x_{\phi(m,n)}$? Where $X={0=x_0<1= x_1<2= x_2< 4=x_3, \cdots}.$

There isn't a "formula" in the usual sense of the word for $\phi,$ just a complex and dull algorithm for computing it, which amounts to computing the inverse of $f$ where $f(n)=x_n.$
